# Unable to run UNIX command after uploading file using webutil_file_transfer

Tags: linux, unix, oracleforms, oas

OS: UNIX Solaries , Oracle Application Server 10g
I designed an Oracle form contains 2 buttons
1- **Upload** button: to let the user upload form.fmb file to the application server using webutil_file_transfer function
2- **Compile** button to compile the uploaded form in the applications server to generete the FMX using the following command

```
 host('/bin/bash /u01/oracle/runtime/test/frmkfccmp.sh >/u01/oracle/runtime/test/log.log');
```

The problem is after uploading the file to the server, the Compile button don't work, although it works well if I close the form then open it again and press the Compile button without pressing the **Upload** button

Any help is appreciated

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overcome this by creating separate form for the compilation only